# Insert select control into DataTable using fnUpdate

Tags: jquery, datatables

Suppose I build an HTML string for a select box `htmlDDL` and want to replace the contents of a cell with position `(x,y)` with the select box.

I tried doing:

```
oTable.fnUpdate(ddlSubset, rowNum, 3, false);
oTable.fnUpdate(ddlSubset.get(), rowNum, 3, false);
oTable.fnUpdate(ddlSubset.html(), rowNum, 3, false);
oTable.fnUpdate(ddlSubset.contents(), rowNum, 3, false);
```

but I get something like:

```
[object Object]
[object HTMLSelectElement]
```

text rendered rather than a nice select control.

Can I use `fnUpdate` to replace the cell contents with a new control?

If so, how?

If not, is there a workaround available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you are trying to insert the jQuery-entity of the select box, not the raw HTML. If you do that, dataTables raises an error and shows the content as `[object HTMLSelectElement]`

Insert the select box as you describe, as *a HTML string* :

```js
var select = '<select><option value="a">A</option><option value="b">B</option></select>';
oTable.fnUpdate(select, rowNum, 3, true, true);
```

See fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/npRJA/, click on "`Click for inserting <select>'s`".

Comment: Wish I could upvote more than once - thank you for the fiddle.